# nodejs createReadStream start from nth line

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have the following code in order to read a text file line by line with nodejs:

```
var lineReader = require('readline').createInterface({
 input: require('fs').createReadStream('log.txt')
});
lineReader.on('line', function (line) {
  console.log(line);
});
lineReader.on('close', function() {
  console.log('Finished!');
});
```

Is there any way to start reading the file from a specific line?

Comment: Why not just discard the beginning nth lines you not interesting?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Node.js Docs](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_createreadstream_path_options) you can specify both `start` and `end` options when creating the stream:

> options can include start and end values to read a range of bytes from the file instead of the entire file. Both start and end are inclusive and start at 0

```
// get file size in bytes
var fileLength = fs.statSync('log.txt')['size'];
var lineReader = require('readline').createInterface({
 input: require('fs').createReadStream('log.txt', {
    // read the whole file skipping over the first 11 bytes
    start: 10
    end: fileLength - 1 
 })
});
```

Comment: the question is about the staring line, not the starting index in the bytes range of the file.

Answer (score 0):

A solution i found,

```
var fs = require('fs');
var split = require('split');
var through = require('through2');

fs.createReadStream('./index.js')
.pipe(split(/(\r?\n)/))
.pipe(startAt(5))
.pipe(process.stdout);

function startAt (nthLine) {
  var i = 0;
  nthLine = nthLine || 0;
  var stream = through(function (chunk, enc, next) {
    if (i>=nthLine) this.push(chunk);
    if (chunk.toString().match(/(\r?\n)/)) i++;
    next();
  })
  return stream;
}
```

See

- split: https://github.com/dominictarr/split
- through2: https://github.com/rvagg/through2